# SharePoint 2013 Troubles changing Share and Edit button colors

Tags: 2013, css, share, edit

I am trying to change the color of the Share and Edit buttons in the top right corner of my SharePoint 2013 site. I was able to change the text color but I am unable to change the buttons next to Share and Edit, as well as the focus content button, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I changed the text color with the following CSS class:

```
.ms-promotedActionButton-icon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery to JavaScript to change the icon. HTML is rendered as follows for Share Button

```
<span style="height:16px;width:16px;position:relative;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;" class="s4-clust ms-promotedActionButton-icon">
    <img src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=38" alt="Share" style="position: absolute; left: -200px; top: -48px;">
</span>
```

So to change the button. You can use following JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ms-promotedActionButton-icon').html('<img src="NEWIMAGEPATH" alt="Share">'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Update Default SharePoint 2013 Icon Colors with **SharePoint Color Palette Tool**, it's  very easy.

This link is going to look at updating the out-of-the-box SharePoint 2013 icons.  This comes in to play if you are creating a branded site.

[Link](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/392/Update-Default-SharePoint-2013-Icon-Colors.aspx)

Yours